# PowerShell - How to parse second item in line followed by newline

Tags: python, powershell

I'm currently writing a program in Python that needs to work on both Windows and *nix platforms. One of the steps is to parse the output from nmap so that the IPs are the only things piped into a txt file. Here's an example of this done with awk:

```
"nmap -n -sn " + targets + " -oG - | awk '/Up$/{print $2}' >" + targetdir + "/targets.txt"
```

I am very unfamiliar with PS, so I don't know what a good equivalent of the above is. Here is an example of what this nmap will produce. Not redacted, everyone has an internal IP :)

```
# Nmap 7.92 scan initiated Wed Sep  1 19:32:15 2021 as: "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Nmap\\nmap.exe" -n -sn -oG - 10.0.0.0/24
Host: 10.0.0.1 ()       Status: Up
Host: 10.0.0.6 ()       Status: Up
Host: 10.0.0.23 ()      Status: Up
Host: 10.0.0.41 ()      Status: Up
Host: 10.0.0.55 ()      Status: Up
Host: 10.0.0.79 ()      Status: Up
Host: 10.0.0.82 ()      Status: Up
Host: 10.0.0.98 ()      Status: Up
Host: 10.0.0.112 ()     Status: Up
Host: 10.0.0.134 ()     Status: Up
Host: 10.0.0.197 ()     Status: Up
Host: 10.0.0.255 ()     Status: Up
Host: 10.0.0.80 ()      Status: Up
# Nmap done at Wed Sep  1 19:32:19 2021 -- 256 IP addresses (13 hosts up) scanned in 4.61 seconds
```

Ideally, I can parse it with PS and pipe it into a file so that it instead looks like:

```
10.0.0.1
10.0.0.6
10.0.0.23
etc
etc
etc
```

I hope I provided an adequate description of the issue, thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: You can do something like this using -match  `$nmapOut | ForEach-Object { if ($_ -match 'Host: (\S+)') { $Matches[1] } } | Out-File $targetdir/targets.txt`  If matched `$Matches[1]` will contain the value of the regex capturing group which will be any non-space character after "Host: "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11954025/daniel). Posting your suggestion as an answer to help other community members.

You can try using `-match`:

```
$nmapOut | ForEach-Object { if ($_ -match 'Host: (\S+)') { $Matches[1] } } | Out-File $targetdir/targets.txt
```

If matched `$Matches[1]` will contain the value of the regex capturing group which will be any non-space character after `Host:

Comment: I will also add that you will need to call powershell after each pipe if running with Python. So `| powershell ForEach Object etc etc | powershell Out-File etc etc`